# How to run tcpdump with 2 parameters in as subprocess in python and how to get its output?

Tags: python, subprocess, tcpdump

I want to run tcpdump with parameters: -n "(dst port 515 or dst port 9100)" -w capture.cap

when I try to do:

```
dump = subprocess.check_output(["tcpdump",'-n "(dst port 515 or dst port 9100)" -w capture.cap'])
```

I get exception:

```
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['tcpdump', '-n "(dst port 515 or dst port 9100)" -w capture.cap']' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

With 1 parameter it works.
Another question is how can I get the output of this command, because it seems to run non-stop.

this code doesn't work as well :

```
p = subprocess.Popen(('sudo', 'tcpdump', '-l -n "(dst port 515 or dst port 9100)"'), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
for row in iter(p.stdout.readline, b''):
print row.rstrip()   # process here
```

Thanks

Comment: You have to pass one argument per item, and no quotes. `check_output()` is not a shell (unless you pass `shell=True`, but this is not necessary in your case)

Comment: so what should I do? I read in another post that I should avoid the using of shell = True

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass one argument per item, and no quotes:

```
subprocess.check_output(['tcpdump', '-n', '(dst port 515 or dst port 9100)', '-w', 'capture.cap'])
```

`check_output()` is not a shell (unless you pass `shell=True`, but this is not necessary in your case): it won't split the arguments for you, and won't interpret quoted strings for you.

Be sure to read the documentation for [`subprocess.run()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run) and check the examples.

By the way, other than the `CalledProcessError` exception, you should have received this error too:

```
tcpdump: invalid option -- ' '
```

That's an helpful hint: it's complaining about the space after `-n`.

Comment: I tried to wrote:                                                                                             p = subprocess.Popen(('sudo', 'tcpdump', '-n', '(dst port 515 or dst port 9100)'), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
for row in iter(p.stdout.readline, b''):
    print row.rstrip()                                                                                                         and I don't get anything, when I run the same command in terminal I get all the traffic

Comment: @azDev: it may be because of buffering. Try using `-l`